# Blender opens with a garbled screen

Tags: installation

I had version 2.81 installed when I began having this problem.  I uninstalled and tried installing it again, but [image] still had the same problem.  I tried other versions but it persists.

I'm running Windows 10 on an ACER Nitro AN515-42, AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Mobile Graphics.

I recently had installed some other programs that didn't work so I uninstalled those programs.  I don't seem to have any problems with any other software, like GIMP or games.

Comment: This is an issue with your graphics driver. An updated driver from [AMDs website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-5-mobile-processors-radeon-vega-graphics/amd-ryzen-5-2500u) should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick, although I had to install the updated driver twice for some reason.